# Python 3.6: List indices must be integers or slices, not tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, typeerror, indices

I am new to Python and trying to make a fill in the blanks quiz. I have researched the error in different forums and still can't manage to correct my code. I feel that I should be able to do this but I just can't see the answer. The error is in def game_start function at the bottom of the code. Here is the repl.it https://repl.it/LN4r/5.This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 62, in <module>
File "python", line 59, in game_start
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Here is is my code:

```
# quizzes below are in order, top to bottom, easy, medium, hard
quizzes = [
    ['''The keyword def is used to define a ___1___ . A function can be used to replace many instances of a ___2___ in a program. The use of if and ___3___ are helpful in declaring an either/or scenario. When you want a loop to be run until a condition is met, the ___4___ is helpful.'''],
['''When writing Python code, indentation must be ___1___ spaces. Also, a ___2___ must be placed at the end of a function. The ___3___ command can be used to query the user. When using parentheses, double or ___4___ ones can be used.'''],
['''What does "d = {}" create? ___1___\n In this example: "x = {"apple":2}" What is the key? ___2___\n What will: "wheel".replace("e","l") output? ___3___\n list1 = [4,2] What is list1 * 2?(include brackets)___4___''']
    ]

# answers for all quizzes.
quiz_answers = [
    ['dictionary', '2', 'whlll', '[4,2,4,2]'],
    ['four', 'colon', 'input', 'single'],
    ['function', 'loop', 'else', 'while']
    ]   

# player level selection
def level_chosen():
    chosen_level = str(input('Please select a level: easy, medium, hard: '))
    if chosen_level == 'easy':
        print("You have chosen easy. Let's play!")
        return quizzes[0], quiz_answers[0]

    elif chosen_level == 'medium':
        print("You have chosen medium. Let's play!")
        return quizzes[1], quiz_answers[1]

    elif chosen_level == 'hard':
        print("You have chosen hard. Let's play!")
        return quizzes[2], quiz_answers[2]

    else:
        print('Not a valid option. Try again.')  
        return level_chosen()

def fill_in_blanks(chosen_level, blank_location = 1, filled_blanks = 0):
    blanks = 4
    while filled_blanks < blanks:
        user_input = input("What is your answer for ___" + str(filled_blanks + 1) + "___?")
        if right_answer(chosen_level, blank_location, user_input):
            if blank_location >= blanks:
                print('You have answered them all correctly!')
                show_new_sentence(chosen_level, blank_location)
            print('Goodjob! Next blank...')
            filled_blanks += 1
            blank_location += 1
        else:
            print('Please try again.')
            fill_in_blanks(chosen_level, blank_location, filled_blanks)

def right_answer(chosen_level, blank_location, answer):
    return str(answer) == quiz_answers[chosen_level][blank_location - 1]

def show_new_sentence(chosen_level, location):
    replace_location = 1
    while replace_location <= location:
        quizzes[chosen_level] = quizzes[chosen_level].replace('___' + str(replace_location) + '___', quiz_answers[chosen_level][replace_location - 1])
        replace_location += 1
    print(quizzes[chosen_level])


def game_start():
    print('Hello! Welcome to my quiz!')
    while True:
        chosen_level = level_chosen()
        print(quizzes[chosen_level])
        fill_in_blanks(chosen_level)

game_start()
```

Comment: If you need help debugging something please provide a [mcve] and don't forget about the **minimal**.

Comment: There's a lot of code here that I'm not going to go through but I'm guessing that whatever you're using as an index for your list is a tuple instead of an integer or slice. Just a shot in the dark here.

Comment: Your `level_cosen()` method returns a tuple of `(quizzes[#],quiz_answers[#])`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your level_chosen function with this.

```
def level_chosen():
    chosen_level = str(input('Please select a level: easy, medium, hard: '))
    if chosen_level == 'easy':
        print("You have chosen easy. Let's play!")
        l = [quizzes[0], quiz_answers[0]]
        return l

    elif chosen_level == 'medium':
        print("You have chosen medium. Let's play!")
        l = [quizzes[1], quiz_answers[1]]
        return l

    elif chosen_level == 'hard':
        print("You have chosen hard. Let's play!")
        l = [quizzes[2], quiz_answers[2]]
        return l

    else:
        print('Not a valid option. Try again.')
        return level_chosen()
```

In your function 'level_chosen', your returns are being converted to tuples. In order to fix this, try replacing "return item1, item2" with "return list(item1, item2)" or "return [item1, item2]".

Tuples are immutable, i.e. they cannot be changed once created. The only problem here is that you want to specify that you do not want a tuple, but instead a list (which is mutable). Adding the function list() around your tuple will convert it to a list.

Comment: Thank you all! Ethan, your answer was very helpful and I got it to work.